# Deployment springboot project on server with error

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot, tomcat8

I can run the project in IDEA, however,I put the project in tomcat/webapps, but it can't work. Who can help me solve this problem? thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: possibly looks like the previous instance is still running. stop that and then try again

Answer (score 0):

The last exception screen shot basically shows that your container did not start as the port that you have given is already in use by a different process.

Comment: as you said, I kill the port 8080 and restart the tomcat, but the project alawys didn't work, 404page, what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Do mvn-clean, mvn-compile on your project directory.
Clean your tomcat server directory, right click on server->properties->switch location from workspace metadata to /server/tomcat...
If any other process is running on your server then stop it, clean Tomcat directory then restart server. If in case, then too it doesn't works then delete the server and configure it again.

Answer (score 0):

Error showing that your  8080 port is already bind or running by some other application.Either change port or kill 8080 from other application.

Comment: I have kill 8080 and restart tomcat, but it no use